# sqlite greater than or equal to 1 query not working

Tags: sqlite

I have a table with field q4 as type integer(10) with default value 0.

I want results where q4 is greater than or equal to 1.

I have tried this in sqlite.

```
SELECT * FROM g101 WHERE  q4 >= 1
```

But it is showing two rows with value of 0.

Please help,

Thank in advance

Comment: Check your column types.

Comment: there's too much space between the WHERE clause and q4. This could be an issue ( no jokes )

Comment: @JorelLokiAmthor I've checked and it doesn't matter.

Comment: do you have a g101 table ? a q4 column ? do you have values for q4 greater or equals to 1 ? any screenshot you can provides ?

Comment: Here is my fields structure screenshot http://www.ktronsystem.com/problem.png

Comment: according to query, It is not expected to get 2 rows.Means it should return zero rows. I have no one rows with value grater than or equal to 1.

Comment: why it is returning two rows with value?

Comment: why it is returning two rows with value zero?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sqlite> create table g101(q4);
sqlite> insert into g101 values (0), ('0');
sqlite> SELECT * FROM g101 WHERE  q4 >= 1;
0
```

Apparently, you have text values in your table.

(Please note that SQLite pretty much [ignores column types](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).)